# Convert an integer to base 10. Given number can be in any base

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I came across this question:

"Given an integer, write a program that converts the given number to a number (in base 10). The given number could be in any base, but the base is unknown."

Provide an algorithm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "the base is unknown," do you mean "you don't know it ahead of time" or "when you're given the number, you don't know the base it's in?"

Comment: @templatetypedef: It's ambiguous if the base isn't known... so it must be variable and not known at compile time.

Comment: Should we send the answer to your professor or your employer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strtol` to convert from whatever base to your computer's native integer format.  Then use `itoa` to convert to a base 10 representation.

Comment: +1 but change `itoa` to `sprintf` (or `snprintf`) for portability.

Comment: Or `stringstream` in C++ for safety.

Answer (score 2):

Given a number k as the digit sequence a<sub>n</sub> a<sub>n-1</sub> ... a<sub>0</sub> in some base b, this value is equal to

a<sub>n</sub>b<sup>n</sup> + a<sub>n-1</sub> b<sup>n - 1</sup> + ... + a<sub>0</sub> b<sup>0</sup>

Thus if you're given the digits of k and the base b, then a simple algorithm would be to iterate across the digits in reverse order, scaling each by the appropriate power of b and adding them all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
int base10dig(char dig) { ... }

int trans(char *num, int base) {
  //the given number is represented as a string
  int ans = 0;
  for (int i = 0 ; num[i] != 0 ; i++) {
    ans = ans * base + base10dig(num[i]);
    //base10dig() is a mapping from a digit (char type) in given base to the base 10 (int type)
    //for example, if the given base is 16, so you should define
    //base('0') = 0, base('1') = 1, ... base('9') = 9, base('A') = 10...
  } 
  return ans;
}
```